# powershell conversting system.array to datatable

Tags: powershell

I have the following query that produces a list of process and their ram utilization.

```
$Process2Ram = get-process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName | Format-Table Name, @{n='Mem (KB)';e={'{0:N0}' -f (($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum / 1KB)};a='right'}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can convert that to a datatable. I was figuring something like this.

```
$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($Process2Ram)
```

Needless to say, this is not working. Anyone have any idea how I can do this and some understanding on why it's not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post an example of how you want to return the data.  Even better is a link to a similar question that illustrates the output format you want.

Comment: Don't use `Format-Table`, use `Select-Object` instead

Comment: You're looking for [`Out-DataTable`](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4208a159-a52e-4b99-83d4-8048468d29dd)

Comment: the format of the results is exactly what you seen when you run the query. One column is process name, the other column is the ram its currently using. Run the query and you'll see exactly what I'm aiming for. I'm just trying to get it into a datatable to make it eaier to work with for later steps. The Out-datatable doesn't seem to work for this, but it's good to know.

Comment: Replace `Format-Table` with `Select-Object`, *then* use `Out-DataTable`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mathias, I had to learn this the hard way. When you use `Format-Table` you are essentially wiping out all the properties/members for whatever you are formatting. What exactly are you trying to do with this data table?

Comment: I'm just trying to get a list of all currently running processes and the ram that each is using. The get-process query works for what I need, but in trying to load it into a datatable so that I can do more with it, it's not wanting to play nice. I tried the select-object instead of format-table, and the breaks the whole query.